# Header and footer disappearing in phone gap app?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an ios app with phonegap. My app contains a page which displays a list of places.Right now i have not given any anchor link or Onclick event for the list items.But the problem is the header and footer is disappearing while clicking or tapping on any list item.My header contains the title of app and footer contains navigation bar.If I tapped again it will appear.But for next tap it will hide and so on. Is there any solution for this problem.?

Comment: Please share some code related to your problem so that we can find out what is wrong with your code;

Comment: Correct ! Share some codes dude ! Make a FIDDLE and post here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your header and footer div

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

This will disable the toggle on header and footer so when you click on the page the footer and header will stay on.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you have a full screen mode turned on. It is done with this attribute:

```
data-fullscreen="true"
```

It must be placed/removed in page/header/footer div. Basically remove this attribute and everything will work just fine.

Official documentation can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html